# Need help for a SQL query (using flask-sqlalchemy) to list all Items that are not listed in a composite many to many Table

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a flask web-app. I would like to get event Organizers to manage a team of workers themselves. Basically, the Organizers create an event and send a request to some Workers which can be accepted or refused. I'd like to make a page listing all the event where the Worker is not yet involved because some Event could be open to any Workers.

```
I have three tables:
[Event]             | [Worker]   | [Worker_Event] (Composite many2many table)     
Id  Name       Open*| Id Name    | Id Id_worker Id_Event state
1 Roland Garos   0  | 1  Tim     | 1  1         1        requested
2 Melbourne Cup  1  | 2  Raf     | 2  1         2        accepted
3 Linux Festival 1  | 3  Dave    | 3  1         3        accepted
4 Holi Festival  1  | 4  Momo    | 4  2         1        requested
5 Oyster party   0  |            | 

*:attribute for is the Even open for any Workers
```

If I would be logged in as worker.Id = 1 (Tim). I'd like to list Holi Festival.
If I would be logged in as worker.Id = 2 (Raf). I'd like to list Melbourne Cup, Linux Festival, Holi Festival.

I know how to list all the festivals that are opened:
listA = Event.query.filter_by(event.Open=1).all()
I know how to list all the festivals (listB) in which a worker is requested or accepted:
listB = Event.query.filter_by(worker_event.Id_worker=current_user.worker.Id).all()

As I would like to use the query.paginate method from Flask-sqlalchemy, I can't just do listA-listB.
Thanks for any contributions

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer myself...

```
db.session.query(Event).filter(~exists().where(and_(Worker_Event.event_id == Event.id,Worker_Event.worker_id == 2))).all()
```

Hope it will help someone in the same case...